# Error on captchas code

Tags: php

Would anyone please tell me why the below code is not warning me that i entered the wrong verification code...

**Below is the code for signup.php**

**signup.php**

```
<table width="450" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="signup_ac.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Sign up</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="75">Name</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="305"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>E-mail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="country" type="text" id="country" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Verification Code</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="Verification Code" type="text" id="Verification Code" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<form method="POST" action="cc.php">
<td><img src="captchas.php"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp;
<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Below is the code for cc.php**

**cc.php**

```
<?php 
if(($_POST['check']) == $_SESSION['check']) { 
echo 'Input OK';
}else{ 
echo 'Input Wrong';        
}
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging (What does `$_POST["check"]` contain, where does the session value come from, etc.). Plus you don't really seem to be showing the really relevant Captcha code.

Comment: what are $_POST['check'] and $_SESSION['check'] values?

Comment: Your form needs be around the input fields you want to submit, and you need to name one of them 'check' (or change cc.php to look for 'Verification Code'). There must be some other error that you're not getting the captcha expected value set on the session though.

Comment: Oh, just spotted you have two forms. That can't be right? Why are you trying to submit the captcha separately from the sign-up data?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `<form>` in your `<form>`. Get rid of the inner form tag and things should work great.

Comment: And before anyone else has the chance...."Yo dog, we heard you like CAPTCHAs, so we put a form in your form so you can submit CAPTCHAs while you submit your forms."

Answer (score 0):

Because both `POST` and `SESSION` **check** are empty

use

```
var_dump($_POST['check']);
```

and

```
var_dump($_SESSION['check']);
```

to check their values and types